# What Defines a Puzzle Chest in Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

This is a Continuation question of [How often do chests respawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376774/how-often-do-chests-respawn) .

Essentially, what determines if a chest is a Puzzle chest? I assume a Steelie chest (the ghosts you guide to a lantern thing) is a puzzle, but what about a chest surrounded by wind that you have to jump over?

Is a combat chest considered a puzzle?

Do they just have to be out in the open with no prior requirement to opening?

Comment: I am curious how to use this information. I am far in the beginning, is it useful to plan "chest runs" at endgame or what? To me the rule is simple: I see chest, I stop doing whatever I was doing and open it.

Comment: mainly to understand the mechanics of chest spawning, so if I leave mondstat for a while to explore liyue, how long to I have to wait before switching over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puzzle chests are commonly associated with the chests that are tied to the fire torches or the elemental pillars. These are the pillars that require specific elements to light them up (usually on a timer), or hidden sets of torches that need to be lit (usually next to a circular pad where the final chest spawns.  Parkour puzzles like the one Dandy offers throughout Tevyat are considered "puzzle" chests as they do not respawn, and only appear once after completion of the challenges.

World elements such as Seelies, combat chests are not considered puzzle chests.  The same applies to the chests in Mondstadt protected by a column of wind.